# ‘struct record’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to use MakeFile for the first time. I try to link these two object files by I get errors from all the functions.
Errors:
‘struct record’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
previous declaration of ‘deleteRecord’ was here int deleteRecord(struct record **, int)

user_interface.c

```
#include "record.h"

int debugmode; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    // my code here
}
    // other functions: AddRecord, printallRecords,...
```

database.h

```
int addRecord (struct record **, int, char [ ],char [ ]);
void printAllRecords(struct record *);
int findRecord (struct record *, int);
int deleteRecord(struct record **, int);
```

database.c

```
#include "database.h"

extern int debugmode; 

int addRecord(struct record ** start, int account, char name[], char address[])
{
    /*my code here*/
    return 0;
}
/*other functions...*/
```

record.h

```
struct record
{
    int                accountno;
    char               name[25];
    char               address[80];
    struct record*     next;
};
```

Comment: You need a line `struct record;` in `database.h` before the function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the "record" type from Database.c which does not include "record.h" where it is defined and hence the error.

You need to add "#include "record.h"" in your Database.c file.

Comment: I tried your code on an online compiler and it works fine with the include.
What error are you getting?

Comment: multiple lines of errors. ‘struct record’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]   database.c:22:0:
database.h:23:5: note: previous declaration of ‘findRecord’ was here
 int findRecord (struct record *, int);  conflicting types for ‘deleteRecord’
 int deleteRecord(struct record ** start, int account)

Comment: I tried your code on an online compiler by adding the include in database.h
https://onlinegdb.com/BJ1KdwLLD

Answer (score 1):

First :

When your compiler is trying to build database.o with the file database.c, it read : `include "database.h"`.

Your functions of the `database.h` use the type : `struct record` but it don't know what is this type at this point. You need include `record.h` in the `database.h` file.

Second :

In the `struct record` declaration, the `struct record *` field's type isn't know until the end of the struct's declaration :

```
struct record
{
    int                accountno;
    char               name[25];
    char               address[80];
    struct record*     next;//Compiler doesn't know struct record here ( not defined )
}; // Here compiler defines the struct record
```

Try something like this :

```
struct record;
struct record
{
    int                accountno;
    char               name[25];
    char               address[80];
    struct record*     next;//Compiler knows the struct record exist 
};
```

And Third :

If you type `include "record.h"` in the main.c and in the database.h, then the struct record will be defined twice ( and it's an error ).
To avoid this error in C : I suggest you to do something like this for any of your header's file :
( example for an header named : `your_header.h` ) :

```
#IFNDEF __YOUR_HEADER_H__ // If any declaration has been done, it won't be done again
#DEFINE __YOUR_HEADER_H__

/**
 Your header stuff ...
( struct record declaration, etc...)
**/

#ENDIF
```

Comment: In which file I should include IFNDEF? I am still getting errors. @Dharman I put in record.h and got these errors  error: unknown type name ‘IFNDEF’

Comment: I have no idea what `IFNDEF`, `DEFINE`, or `ENDIF` is supposed to mean.  That's not any version of C or C++ I ever heard of :).  I can only assume they mean `#ifndef`, `#define`, and `#endif`.

Comment: @JoanaF. You should include it in any .h ( header file ), to force the compiler to not read the .h 2 times. 
Btw, here it's __YOUR_HEADER_H__ ( but it need to be different for any .h )